# Анимация CSS для кастомного макета

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Свойство CSS  transition: 3s; для состояний div в шаблоне  MyIconLayout не работает ((
Без него поворот иконки идет рывками, что очень не красиво...Кто-нибудь сможет подсказать как решить это проблему? спасибо!

```
MyIconLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            '<div style="transform:rotate({{options.rotate}}deg); transition: 3s;">{% include "default#image" %}</div>'
        );

MyPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([52.33901161240372,42.94469719054045], {
            hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
            balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка'
        }, {
            // Опции.
            // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
            iconLayout: MyIconLayout,     
            // Своё изображение иконки метки.
            iconImageHref: 'skin/myicon.png',
            // Размеры метки.
            iconImageSize: [50, 52],
            // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
            // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
            iconImageOffset: [-25, -33],
            //начальный угол поворота
            iconRotate: 0
        }); 
         myMap.geoObjects.add(RadarPlacemark);       

function set_myicon_angle(angle)
    {   
    /* alert(angle); */
         MyPlacemark .options.set({
            iconRotate: angle
        });
    }
```

Comment: мб потому что в одном месте написано `rotate` а в доругом `iconRotate` ?

Comment: увы, не в этом дело( изменение угла то происходит но рыками

Comment: а. я так понимаю тогда, что iconRotate какое-то стандартное свойство из API карт? не используйте его тогда. Попробуйте сделать свой аналог через properties, или как оно там.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать анимацию метки с помощью свойства "transform". Получается без рывков, посмотреть пример можно [здесь](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_layout)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)